# Searching between dates on a CHAR type field

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has a field in which dates are stored, the problem is that the field type is `CHAR(10)` and I'm being asked to query for data between certain dates.

I don't want to change the field type because I'm not sure how's that gonna affect the frontend application.

Is there a way of querying for results between dates without making changes to the data type?

Regards.

Comment: Change it, test it, release it. Saves much more pain in the long run.

Comment: How are dates exactly stored? Are they like `'2015-03-22'` or `'20150322'` or `'2015/03/22'` or `'22-03-2015'` or `'03-22-2015'` (or somtehing else)?

Comment: Current format is `29/03/2015`

Comment: @ZQL In this format, you'll need to make sure '02/03/2015' evaluates to the 2nd March and not the 3rd February. Always a risky way to save dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast your date to perform where clause on it just like this.

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, MyStringDateField, 120) BETWEEN @DateParam1 AND @DateParam2
```

The last parameter in CONVERT is the date format. You must choose the one that match your text data of your date. You can find the list [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-CA/library/ms187928.aspx)

You must be aware that if a string does not match a date for a particular record, your query will fail with a message saying that the data XYZ cannot be converted to DATETIME type.

Comment: Only thing I would add is if you're expecting a lot of rows to be returned, it might be faster to dump your SELECT into a temp table, index the converted datetime column and then implement your WHERE clause.

Comment: Cheers dude, works perfect!